# Digit Recogntion using OpenCV on android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm a first time Android and OpenCV developer and I would very much appreciate your help and some advise. I would like to extract and identify digits inputted by a mobile phone camera.

**How do i approach this? What would be the best way to approach it and what are the steps?**

It would help me very much if you could be as specific as possible.

This is how the picture can be inputted:

[image]

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python.  It is in python, but you can get a simple logic on how to do it using kNN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some great discussions that I've seen around here and other places that can really help you achieve what you are looking for:

- [How to use Opencv for Document Recognition with OCR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7542194/176769)
- [Basic OCR in OpenCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20160508124832/http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/)
- [Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9413216/176769)
- On [SuDoKu Grabber with OpenCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915165623/http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv-plot/), check [item 5 Recognizing digits](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317181458/http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv-recognizing-digits/).

Comment: Thanks for those great links. The Sudoku grabber has moved. New URL is: http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv-plot/

Comment: three out of five links are no longer working.

Comment: I'm not surprised! It's a 6+ years old answer.