# How to improve accuracy of OpenCV template matching

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I tried using MatchTemplate() to match numbers in image. For example, the numbers are [0985-977-735] in image. 
And got the results as following:(number, location)
[(0, 1), (3, 103), (5, 33), (5, 116), (7, 62), (7, 73), (7, 85), (8, 21), (9, 11), (9, 53)]

But in most situations, the accuracy is very low.

[0983-945-180]:
[(0, 113), (1, 93), (3, 31), (4, 62), (5, 74), (8, 103), (9, 11), (9, 53)]
the first zero and eight can't be recognized.

[0932-509-607]
[(0, 103), (2, 31), (3, 21), (5, 54), (6, 92), (7, 113), (9, 72)]
the first, second zero and first nine can't be recognized.

[0911-873-752]
[(0, 1), (1, 22), (1, 33), (2, 113), (3, 72), (5, 105), (7, 92), (8, 52), (9, 11)]
the first seven can't be recognized.

part of the code as following:

```
import cv
for i in range(10):
    template_im = cv.LoadImage(template_file, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    width = original_im.width - template_im.width + 1
    height = original_im.height - template_im.height +1
    result_image = cv.CreateImage((width, height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
    cv.Zero(result_image)
    cv.MatchTemplate(original_im, template_im, result_image, cv.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    (_, R, _, max_loc) = cv.MinMaxLoc(result_image)

    if R < 0.90:
        pass
    else:
        phone_number_location.append((i, max_loc[0]))
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Can you post samples of images you're working on?

Comment: If you are looking for a digit OCR, you can see a simple implementation here using OpenCV-Python.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python/9620295#9620295

Comment: possible duplicate of [digit recogntion using OpenCV on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107258/digit-recogntion-using-opencv-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to use SimpleCV for this. It is written in python. Most of the things you require are in it. I wrote a basic image stitching app in just 15 lines of code. Hope this helps. Use the code in github because template matching is new in SimpleCV.
Hope this helps.