# How To Read numbers from Image using OpenCV 2.1

Tags: opencv

Previously I posted this question in this forum and as per as experts suggestion, they recommended me to use OpenCV for extracting data from the image.

I'm new to OpenCV, basically I learnt to install OpenCV 2.1  with Visual Studio 2008 and then I worked with simple programs like to load the images, invert and save images.

Then I'm trying to read the numbers from the image. I searched a lot in Google and OpenCV tutorials PDF, I didn't get any solution.

Please can anyone guide me about this?
Or a simple walkthrough for reading the numbers from the image..

Thank you..

Comment: Yes.. i can get a lot information about object detection like face recognition,cvFindCountours(),cvMatchTemplate(). But this is not as my requirement :(

Comment: Then how do you expect to recognize numbers? You will have to aply object detection techniques. It is not different from a face.

Comment: Ok.. I will look for object detection techniques now..

Comment: possible duplicate of [digit recogntion using OpenCV on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107258/digit-recogntion-using-opencv-on-android)

Comment: Hi karlphilip.. Am having small doubt on this puzzle link http://www.aishack.in/2010/08/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv/ , Here can we read or access the numbers in the cell ??

Answer (score 2):

A example of a basic OCR with OpenCV:
https://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/20/basic-ocr-in-opencv.html

Comment: ok so try this: [http://blog.damiles.com/2010/12/segmentation-and-feature-extraction-contours-and-blob-detection/](http://blog.damiles.com/2010/12/segmentation-and-feature-extraction-contours-and-blob-detection/) after the segmentation you can match with a template with the function: cvMatchTemplate

Comment: Hi.. As per as ur suggestion i applied cvFindCountour() to the image. Output draws the countours or like boundary line on the numbers. But how to retrieve the numbers to my application ..? I have uploaded  two images, Original image & new image after applying countours.Original one: http://i.imgur.com/bRcJd.jpg        New image(applied countours):http://i.imgur.com/rxKNv.png. Please let me Know to retrieve the numbers..?

Comment: The link is dead